# Telegram Bot - Share content from telegram to whats app

Tags: telegram-bot

Want to invoke android share or open whats app using "whatsapp://send?text=....." to share messages from telegram to whats app.

Was trying to open using URL in inline_keyboard.

But Telegram says BAD URL. Is there a way I can open an external browser from telegram so that my URL call to Whats app works? Or is there a better way?